# what are different types of state in calling (telephony)

Tags: call, phone-call, telephony, telephonymanager, core-telephony

I want to know in brief about different types of state in telephony (like waiting ,pending,ringing )and the difference between waiting and pending state in call.

Answer (score 1):

There is many different terms to identify telephony states but [**CSTA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-supported_telecommunications_applications) (Computer Supported Telecommunication Services) standard from **ECMA**  has defined a telephony model quite usable.

The telephony model goal is to describe the relation between telephonic devices and calls.  The problem is that there is two legitimate points of view, on one hand you have a device oriented point of view (`endpoint view`) where the focus is a device involved in several calls ; on the other hand the call oriented point of view (`global view`) where the call evolve in time with several device.

The endpoint states in **CSTA** is :

- **Alerting/Offered** – Indicates an incoming call at an endpoint. Typically the connection may be ringing or it may be in a pre-alerting (e.g. offered) condition.
- **Connected** – Indicates that a connection is actively participating in a call. This connection state can be the result of an incoming or outgoing call.
- **Failed** – Indicates that call progression has stalled. Typically this could represent that an outgoing call attempt that encountered a busy endpoint.
- **Held** – Indicates that an endpoint is no longer actively participating in a call. For implementations that support multiple calls per endpoint (i.e. line), a connection could be Held while the line is used to place another call (consultation transfer on an analog line, for example).
- **Initiated** – A transient state, usually indicating that the endpoint is initiating a service (e.g. dial-tone) or the device is being prompted to go off-hook.
- **Null** – There is no relationship between the call and the endpoint.
- **Queued** – Indicates that the call is temporarily suspended at a device (e.g. call has been parked, camped on).

The global view in CSTA is more complicated because a call state is the set of endpoint states but I try to briefly describe basic simple call states with Alice calls bob :

- **Null/Idle**(no call) -> `Alice(Null)-Bob(Null)`
- **Pending**(Alice dials) -> `Alice(Initiated)-Bob(Null)`
- **Originated**(Alice wait) -> `Alice(Connected)-Bob(Null)`
- **Delivered**(Bob set is ringing) -> `Alice(Connected)-Bob(Alerting)`
- **Established**(Bob answers) -> `Alice(Connected)-Bob(Connected)`
- **Terminated**(Bob hangs on) -> `Alice(Connected)-Bob(Null)`

And to get back to your specific concern about pending versus waiting; waiting imply that the call has been put in a wait queue :

- **Queued**(call is queued) -> `Alice(Connected)-Bob(Queued)`

Pending is transient state but waiting can be quite long in that case a voice guide or music is played.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got that "pending" state from, but in `TelephonyManager` there are only 3 states:

1. `CALL_STATE_IDLE` - No activity
2. `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` - There's an
   active call (either incoming or outgoing)
3. `CALL_STATE_RINGING` -
   There's an incoming call waiting for the user to answer

You can detect between an incoming call and an outgoing by the state transition:

- `CALL_STATE_IDLE` => `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` - suggests an outgoing call
- `CALL_STATE_RINGING` => `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` - suggests an incoming call

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_IDLE